# Incompatible value type Boolean for Map<Id,Set<String>>

Tags: apex

I am trying to insert data from csv file to salesforce from vf page using apex.
In the below pic column A, B, C needs to go to object Account and column D should go to another object Type__c and Type__c should be a child of Account.

When Id's are same one record is getting created in Account simulataneoulsy 1 record should get created in Type__c object if Type is having same value for that ID.And if column A, B , C are same but D is different, one record should get created for Account having one account number and 2 record should get crated in Type__c object .

[image]

below is the code . I am unable to save it as it is throwing an error

> Error: Compile Error: Incompatible value type Boolean for `Map<Id,Set<String>>` at line 67 column 17

```
  public class importDataFromCSVController {
public Blob csvFileBody{get;set;}
public string csvAsString{get;set;}
public String[] csvFileLines{get;set;}
public List<account> acclist{get;set;}
    public map<string, string> csvmap = new map<string, string>();
    public map<string, Account> accmap = new map<string, Account>();
    List<Type__c> typeList = new List<Type__c>();
  public importDataFromCSVController(){
    csvFileLines = new String[]{};
    acclist = New List<Account>(); 
  }

  public void importCSVFile(){
       try{
           csvAsString = csvFileBody.toString();
           csvFileLines = csvAsString.split('\n'); 


      for(Integer i=1;i<csvFileLines.size();i++){

           string[] csvRecordData = csvFileLines[i].split(',');
                if(csvmap.containsKey(csvRecordData[0])){
           csvmap.put(csvRecordData[0],csvmap.get(csvRecordData[0])+','+csvRecordData[2]);
               }
                else{
                csvmap.put(csvRecordData[0],csvRecordData[2]) ;
                    }
            }

           system.debug('@@@@@@'+ csvmap);
  /*  for(string str : csvmap.keyset())
     {
       Account accObj = new Account() ;

           accObj.name = str ;             
           accObj.test__c= csvmap.get(str);                                                                      
           acclist.add(accObj); 

      }   

        insert acclist;*/
        for(string str : csvmap.keyset())
{
    Account accObj = new Account() ;
    accObj.name = str ;             
    accObj.test__c= csvmap.get(str);                                                                      
    accmap.put(str , accObj); 
}

insert accmap.values();

Map<Id, set<string>> typeAccMap = new Map<Id, set<string>>();
for(Integer i=1;i<csvFileLines.size();i++){
    string[] csvRecordData = csvFileLines[i].split(',');
    if(accmap.containsKey(csvRecordData[0])){
        Account acc = accmap.get(csvRecordData[0]);
        if(typeAccMap.containsKey(acc.id))
        {
            Set<String> typeSet = typeAccMap.get(acc.id);
            if(! typeSet.contains(csvRecordData[3]))
            system.debug('@@@@@' + typeSet);
            system.debug('@@@@@' + csvRecordData[3]);
            {
                Type__c t = new Type__c (Name = csvRecordData[3], Account__c = acc.id); 
                typeList.add(t);
               // typeAccMap.put(csvRecordData[0], typeAccMap.get(csvRecordData[0]).add(csvRecordData[3]));
Set<Id> tmpSet = typeAccMap.get(csvRecordData[0]);
tmpSet.add(Id.valueOf(csvRecordData[3]));
typeAccMap.put(csvRecordData[0], tmpSet);
            }
        }
        else
        {
              Type__c t = new Type__c (Name = csvRecordData[3], Account__c = acc.id); 
              typeList.add(t);
              typeAccMap.put(csvRecordData[0], new Set<String>{csvRecordData[3]});
        }

       }
insert typeList;
       }
       }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ApexPages.Message errorMessage = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'An error has occured while importin data Please make sure input csv file is correct');
            ApexPages.addMessage(errorMessage);
        }  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Apex the `Set` class' `add()` method returns a `Boolean` which returns true if the `Set` changed as a result of the call (see the [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_set.htm)).  In your code:

```
typeAccMap.put(csvRecordData[0], typeAccMap.get(csvRecordData[0]).add(csvRecordData[3]));
```

is trying to put `<Id, Boolean>` instead of `<Id, Set<String>>`.

Try replacing line 67 with the following:

```
Set<Id> tmpSet = typeAccMap.get(csvRecordData[0]);
tmpSet.add(Id.valueOf(csvRecordData[3]));
typeAccMap.put(csvRecordData[0], tmpSet);
```

Comment: Hi Jeff.. can u let me know which part of my code needs to be modified..How to call typeAccMap.get(csvRecordData[0]).add(csvRecordData[3]) anf then add then add set to the map..

Comment: I have edited the end of my answer to hopefully be clearer.

Comment: another error poped up... Illegal assignment from Set<String> to Set<Id> at line 68 column 24

Comment: Should be fixed now.

Comment: the error is still there....can u plz check..

Comment: I have updated the code above which is giving me error

Comment: if i change Set<Id> tmpSet to Set<String> tmpSet the error is not showing and class is able to get saved.. But when uploading the csv file..i am getting an error ..Record ID: cannot specify Id in an insert call ..in debug log ....System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0 with id a0H9000000LmiemEAB; first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an insert call: [Id]

Comment: In this process..the below two records in the pic..Type__c being a child record , the values Customer-Channel , Customer-Direct should get saved as two records but its not happening..

Comment: Try changing the insert to an upsert then.  That should get rid of the DmlException.

Comment: so change of Set<Id> to Set<String> is correct?

Comment: Sorry, yes.  There are some situations where `Set` and `Id` and interchangeable, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: using upsert instead of insert has removed the exception now..but another issue has come out is - the 1st two records in the above pic has similar values in Type column..So while upsert it should create one record in Type__c which is Customer - Channel.. But it has created two records..